# WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

I am using WSL 2 for Microsoft Windows 10 (Ubuntu 20.04 WSL), and when I try to compile my code and run a Virtualbox process, using the ISO my code made, I get a really odd error.

```
osdev@DESKTOP-2VDARGU:/mnt/c/Users/(hiding name)/Desktop/MyOS$ WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
         Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
         headers, most likely linux-headers-standard.

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
Qt WARNING: could not connect to display
Qt FATAL: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
```

I have tried everything. I installed so many headers, I installed the virtualbox-dkms package, re-configured it, and much more. I'm baffled on why this doesn't work. If I could get some help, I would appreciate it very much.

If you need the code for the process that starts the VM, here you go:

```
run: mykernel.iso
    (killall VirtualBox && sleep 1) || true
    VirtualBox --startvm 'My Operating System' &

install: mykernel.bin
    sudo cp $< /boot/mykernel.bin
```

If you need any more code, please respond in the comments.

EDIT: I tried running modprobe vboxdrv and it threw this error:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.128-microsoft-standard
```

EDIT 2: output of rebuilding virtualbox-dkms:

```
-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  virtualbox
Version: 6.1.10
Kernel:  5.4.0-53-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

vboxdrv.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.4.0-53-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxnetadp.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.4.0-53-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxnetflt.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.4.0-53-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.1.10
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-6.1.10 DKMS files...
It is likely that 4.19.128-microsoft-standard belongs to a chroot's host
Building for 5.4.0-53-generic
Building initial module for 5.4.0-53-generic
Done.

vboxdrv.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-53-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-53-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-53-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
```

Comment: You're trying to run Virtualbox under WSL2 (which is itself a Hyper-V VM)? Er, why?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization <- I think the last paragraph applies to you

Comment: Anyway, try as root `modprobe vboxdrv` then look at the end of the output of `dmesg` what it barfed out.

Comment: So it didn't actually build the driver. Next stop: the output of reconfiguring the virtualbox-dkms package and why it's not building for 4.19.128-microsoft-standard. (Note: I don't think this whole thing will work, why are you doing this again?)

Comment: @dratenik check the edit

Comment: Do you actually need the acceleration? If you are running your own OS experiment, try it under qemu. https://manpages.debian.org/testing/qemu-system-x86/qemu-system-x86_64.1.en.html The default mode (tcg) should be dynamic re-compilation, requires no privileges and no kernel support. It is not excitingly fast (below ~20 % native?), but do you care?

Comment: "It is likely that 4.19.128-microsoft-standard belongs to a chroot's host" -> "you're running version XYZ but I don't see any of its files on the filesystem"

Comment: @dratenik i will check it out, I’m use to working with Virtualbox ;-;

Comment: @dratenik I do need the acceleration, because im testing with GUI's and drivers, and I wanna use all my 6 cores and 16 gigs of RAM

Comment: If you need performance, running a nested Virtualbox under Hyper V is not the way to achieve it.